# Can anybody recommend a comprehensive source for understanding mathematical notations?

Tags: notation

I foten struggle with understanding some of the mathematics written down in papers. This stuggle is often due to notation used. Therefore, I was wondering whether somebody is aware of a resource that explains how read the formulas. I am talking about signs like: ∑, y||2 and some others.

Comment: [A good start.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)

Comment: @Jochem To the right you can find, under the $\text{Related}$  tab, similar questions which might be useful.